# jackson serializer - accessing private properties

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have a `Spring Boot 2` application with a model of private properties and public getters / setters. Jackson is `2.10.0` version.

I need a custom serialiser to output `JSON` without expanding some references. From what I have read, if the property is private the `Jackson` can not access it and a compile error ensues. Unless there are public getters when it should work. But it does not.

But if I set the properties in the model to public, no errors.

Equally if I use the getter rather than property in the serialiser then all is well.

I have misread this and the serialiser really does treat private as private?

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ClimateSerializer.class)
public class Climate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "climate_gen")
    private long id;

    private float temperature;
    private float humidity;

    .... getters and setters
}
```

Serializer

```
public class ClimateSerializer extends StdSerializer<Climate> {

    public ClimateSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ClimateSerializer(Class<Climate> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
      final Climate value, final JsonGenerator jgen, final SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.getId());
        jgen.writeNumberField("temperature", value.getTemperature());
        jgen.writeNumberField("humidity", value.getHumidity());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

This compiles.

if the write*Field calls are replaced with

```
jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.id);
etc
etc
```

Then I get a compile error. Unable to access private property. Which goes against what I have read. A private property is accessible for `Jackson` if there is a public getter.

Obviously using getters directly is fine. It works. But I would like to know if the various docs I have read are wrong.

Comment: You could add [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question to help to understand and answer better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement custom serialiser and do not make properties public at the same time you can implement `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializable` interface in `Climate` class directly:

```
class Climate implements JsonSerializable {

    private long id;

    private float temperature;
    private float humidity;

    @Override
    public void serialize(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeNumberField("id", id);
        gen.writeNumberField("temperature", temperature);
        gen.writeNumberField("humidity", humidity);
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer) {
    }
}
```

Your problem is not related with `Jackson` directly. Rather with [access modifiers](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/access-modifiers.html). When you want to use default serialisation, `Jackson` uses [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html) wrapped in many features to serialise given `POJO` class to `JSON`. So, it is true that `Jackson` can use private fields but in your cases you want to implement custom serialiser and you need to use reflection yourself to make it work. In other case, you can use `default` access modifier and put custom serialiser `ClimateSerializer` and class `Climate` in the same package to make it work.

Comment: The easiest approach was justy to keep properties private and use the public getters directly. Certainly every blog and tutorial says that with public getters then private properties can be accessed directly in the custom serializer but I must have set something that stops that.